# Sharing Wi-Fi with rental dorm using different frequenzy bands?

Tags: network, wifi, router

We're in the process of renting out our house dorm, and discussing networking options. We currently got an ASUS router that's broadcasting both a 2.4GHz and a 5GHz network.

**The question is:** Would it introduce a security concern to allow the rental takers access to our 2.4GHz network, whilst we would continue using the 5GHz one? They're both connected to the same router, so I have a feeling that this could be a security problem. Thought it is worth mentioning that the administrator account of the router interface is changed from the default admin/admin combination.

Answer (score 1):

With out any more details I would say yes, this is a bad idea.

2.4ghz and 5ghz are not isolated even if you give them both separate SSIDs they will still connect to the same network, both 2.4 and 5 traffic will use the same network.

you would basically just deciding who gets the faster wireless speed.

Comment: I see, that's what I thought. What kind of networking attacks would be typical for this, and is there any article or search term that would be suitable for me to read up on the subject?

Comment: @Erik that would depend on your knowledge and experience I guess, as a quick fix I could suggest buting a router with an RJ45 wan and plugging it into one of the LAN ports on your current router. this will allow you to set a static IP to that port and control very harshly if you so wish the traffic allowed in and out of said network. though doing this can sometimes cause NAT issues, though only minor ones. this would place them on a separate network. it wont mitigate all risk but its an ok way to go about things

Answer (score 1):

As @silverpenguin says, the separate wireless channels are not logically separate.

At the very least, you should use a router that allows Virtual Networks (VLANs) to be set up. Then set up a separate guest SSID that links to a separate guest VLAN.

Note that a VLAN is not really considered "secure", not enough for high-security connections. But it is sufficient for most use.